# Unable to select/copy text in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am useing the Entry control in vb.net xamarin form which is editable. To avoid any edit I used following code

```
IsReadOnly="True"
```

But then I am unable to copy that item after long press.

Please help how can I use that control or any other control which is non-editable but copiable.

Comment: Is it always readonly? If so, can you just use a label?

Comment: Or add a button beside and use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/clipboard

Comment: Can it be possible that Entry control would be read only but it can be select and copy on long press

Comment: I think it's more efficient to control `IsReadOnly` by using a checkbox.